# Bluej, how to jump a line?

Tags: methods, bluej

I'm trying to create a textbased game using bluej,
I've got everything working properly, but I'd like to know how I can jump to another line of code to stop whatever comes after that, and carry on from that line, and how to write that in a method.

Comment: Some code would help.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is essentially a `goto`. Don't use `goto`. You should be using methods and conditionals.

Comment: might be dumb question, but why not?

Comment: There is ALWAYS a solution that doesn't use a `goto`. Post your code as it is now.